# How to count missing values from two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, missing-data

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
**Contig_A**    **Contig_B**   

  Contig_0        Contig_1 
  Contig_3        Contig_5
  Contig_4        Contig_1
  Contig_9        Contig_0
```

I want to count how many contig ids (from Contig_0 to Contig_1193) are not present in either Contig_A column of Contig_B.

For example: if we consider there are total 10 contigs here for this data frame (Contig_0 to Contig_9), then the answer would be 4 (Contig_2, Contig_6, Contig_7, Contig_8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a vector of all the values that you want to check (`all_contig`) which is `Contig_0` to `Contig_10` here. Use `setdiff` to find the absent values and `length` to get the count of missing values.

```
cols <- c('Contig_A', 'Contig_B')
#If there are lot of 'Contig' columns that you want to consider
#cols <- grep('Contig', names(df), value = TRUE)

all_contig <- paste0('Contig_', 0:10)

missing_contig <- setdiff(all_contig, unlist(df[cols]))
#[1] "Contig_2"  "Contig_6"  "Contig_7"  "Contig_8"  "Contig_10"

count_missing <- length(missing_contig)
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

by `match`,

```
x <- c(0:9)
contigs <- sapply(x, function(t) paste0("Contig_",t))
df1 <- data.frame(
  Contig_A = c("Contig_0", "Contig_3", "Contig_4", "Contig_9"),
  Contig_B = c("Contig_1", "Contig_5", "Contig_1", "Contig_0")
)
xx <- c(df1$Contig_A,df1$Contig_B)
contigs[is.na(match(contigs, xx))]

[1] "Contig_2" "Contig_6" "Contig_7" "Contig_8"
```

In your case, just change `x` as `x <- c(0,1193)`